# Does a finally block run even if you throw a new Exception?

Tags: java, exception

In this code will `someVar` be set even if the catch block is executed and the second Exception is thrown?

```
public void someFunction() throws Exception {
    try {
        //CODE HERE
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        this.someVar= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there are circumstances where the behaviour is not as expected, as indicated by @GaryF

Comment: It is worth noting that the final block may not execute as expected if it throws an exception, or does a return.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Yes, the finally blocks always runs... except when:

- The thread running the try-catch-finally block is killed or interrupted
- You use `System.exit(0);`
- The underlying VM is destroyed in some other way
- The underlying hardware is unusable in some way

Additionally, if a method in your finally block throws an uncaught exception, then nothing after that will be executed (i.e. the exception will be thrown as it would in any other code). A very common case where this happens is `java.sql.Connection.close()`.

As an aside, I am guessing that the code sample you have used is merely an example, but be careful of putting actual logic inside a finally block. The finally block is intended for resource clean-up (closing DB connections, releasing file handles etc), not for must-run logic. If it must-run do it before the try-catch block, away from something that could throw an exception, as your intention is almost certainly functionally the same.

Comment: What do you mean here by "The thread running the try-catch-finally block is [...] interrupted"? Perhaps that documentation is poorly worded, but Thread.interrupt() will not cause the finally block to be skipped, whether thrown from the try or the catch block. Does this use "interrupted" to mean something more violent, like Thread.stop()?

Comment: @Joe: Yes, I think the documention is a little poorly worded here, and that they mean a general interruption to the thread's activity.

Comment: @GaryF - I think you are quoting from the JLS.  The wording of the JLS is sometimes a bit strange, but you will typically find that the meaning of the strange terminology is defined clearly elsewhere in the document.  The JLS is a *specification* and has precision (rather than readability) as its primary goal.

Comment: @Stephen C - Actually, that came from the JavaSE tutorial (linked to by others). It may be similarly worded in the JLS, but I can't find the relevant part. I'd have expected this in chapter 11 (Exceptions), chapter 14 (Statements) or chapter 15 (Expressions), but can't see anything referring to interruptions explicitly. I'd certainly be interested in seeing that.

Comment: @GaryF - I see.  Actually the JLS talks about "normal" and "abrupt" termination of statements, and there is a section (14.1) that defines the terminology.  The behavior of `finally` is then specified in terms of normal and abrupt terminations.

Comment: Can we use `finally` to do `setAutoCommit(true)` ? Or does that form part of the code logic?

Comment: I trust you. But do you have any Oracle doc ?

Comment: so why then stupid tools complain about resources not being closed

Answer (score 12):

Yes.

See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> The finally block *always* executes when
>   the try block exits.

Exceptions:

> Note: If the JVM exits while the try
>   or catch code is being executed, then
>   the finally block may not execute.
>   Likewise, if the thread executing the
>   try or catch code is interrupted or
>   killed, the finally block may not
>   execute even though the application as
>   a whole continues.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, block always executes.

```
public class ExceptionTest {

public static void someFunction(String input) throws Exception {
    try {
        if( input.equals("ABC") ) {
            System.out.println("Matched");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Input Is "+input+" Finally Executed!!!");
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        System.out.println("********* Test with VALUE ********* ");
        someFunction("ABC");
        System.out.println("\r\n********* Test with NULL  ********* ");
        someFunction(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

[image: Java Try Catch Finally Block with Throw]

Answer (score 3):

Finally is always executed, no matter what your case is i.e

- try-catch-finally block
- throws

For unchecked exceptions, java does not mandate, error handling.
this being the reason, if an unchecked exception occurs in finally block then and no handling is done for that, then code written below this point (where the error has occurred) will not be executed.

So I suggest to always handle all the exceptions may it be checked or unchecked.
This way you can make sure that code block in finally is also executed no matter if unchecked exception also occurs. you have a place in sub-nest catch and **Finally** block to get your necessary work done.

Answer (score 1):

[The finally block always executes when the try block exits](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).unless you've System.exit(0) in your try or catch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `finally` block executes always except the case you call System.exit() because it stops Java VM.

Comment: Shutdown hooks are still called after System.exit(), but existing non-system threads are all stopped.