# Not able to catch Custom Exception using Java

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to catch a SQL exception. I've three layers,

1. Controller 2. Impl class 3. DAO (There is an interface in the flow too, on a high level im putting as 3 levels for description).

### Controller

```
try {
        // Call interface which in turn will call Impl
    } catch (MyException e) {
        logger.debug(e);
    } catch(Exception e) {          
        logger.debug(e);
    }
        return null;
```

### Impl

```
 try {
        purchaseDto = purDAO.createPurchase(clientId);
    } catch(MyException e) {  --> It should catch here, as I'm throwing MyException in DAO
        throw e;
    }catch(Exception e) { --> DAO Exception is being catch here
        throw e;
    }
```

### DAO

```
 try {
          // My business logic goes here     
    } catch (SQLException e) {            
        throw new MyException (e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage()); --> It is catching here, from here it should go back to Impl catch block of MyException
     } catch (Exception e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pt.close();
        try{                
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### My exception

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

/**
 * 
 */
private int errorCode;
private String errorDesc;


public int getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

public String getErrorDesc() {
    return errorDesc;
}

public void setErrorDesc(String errorDesc) {
    this.errorDesc = errorDesc;
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MyException () {
    super();
}

public MyException (int errorCode, String errorDesc) {
    super();
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.errorDesc = errorDesc;
}



}
```

I'm getting a sql exception in DAO layer, where I'm throwing my custom exception if I get any sql exception. When it goes back to Impl, it goes to normal exception catch block(It gets as null pointer exception message). Ideally it should go to My custom exception catch, right? Where I'm I doing wrong. Please rectify me.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that MyException is throwing an Exception, which explains why you're getting an Exception , rather than a MyException. Post the code for MyException.

Comment: @dsp_user, internally its a null pointer exception, but still I'm throwing my own exception right? which should override?

Comment: An NPE is not an SqlException so there's something wrong with your code. Post the rest of the code.

Comment: @dsp_user, Updated the code, in DAO, I'm just adding the finally block.

Comment: Please, post the code (the definition) for MyException as well.

Comment: @dsp_user.. Updated MyException class too

Comment: @dsp_user, the error is because a table is not found. I just want to wrap this message in MyException class

Comment: Instead of calling just super() call super(errorDesc, errorCode). Both the exception message and code are already in the super class (Exception) so they don't have to be in the subclass. BTW, if you are getting an NPE internally and not an SqlException, then your flow is not exactly as you described.

Comment: @dsp_user, There is no logic after exception in DAO, its simply going to Exception of Impl, not MyException

Comment: @dsp_user.. The issue was with pt.close().. pt was null. Big stupid mistake of mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely scenario is that the line `pt.close();` in the DAO class throws an exception. In that case, because an exception happens in the finally block, your exception is not thrown.
This scenario is explained here in more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4264937/6169266

Comment: You're right. pt is null. I made this stupid mistake.