# The order of return value with try catch finally

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I use this code to test try catch finally:

```
public class My{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fun1());
        System.out.println(fun2());
    }

    public static int fun1() {
        int a = 1;
        try {
            System.out.println(a / 0);
            a = 2;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            a = 3;
            return a;
        } finally {
            a = 4;
        }
        return a;

    }

    public static int fun2() {
        int a = 1;
        try {
            System.out.println(a / 0);
            a = 2;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            a = 3;
            return a;
        } finally {
            a = 4;
            return a;
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
3
4
```

I know that finally will always run. I think the result of the two functions should be 4, but actually `fun1()` is 3 and the `fun2()` is 4. Why?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264874/does-a-finally-block-run-even-if-you-throw-a-new-exception#:~:text=The%20finally%20block%20always%20executes,Exceptions%3A&text=Likewise%2C%20if%20the%20thread%20executing,application%20as%20a%20whole%20continues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple returns: Which one sets the final return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309964/multiple-returns-which-one-sets-the-final-return-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is closely related, although it returns literals but not variables: [Multiple returns: Which one sets the final return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309964/multiple-returns-which-one-sets-the-final-return-value)

In `fun1` the return value is set via `return a` in the catch-block. At that line the value of `a` is copied into the return value. Changing `a` later does not change the return value.

In `fun2` you have an explicit return in the `finally` block, so the return value in the finally block is what is returned.

Please read carefully through the answers in the question above for why you should not write code like that.

Another related question is this one: [Returning from a finally block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java)

Comment: This is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In simple words when a function returns something it returns from the last executed return statement. in `fun2()` first return value is `3` which gets overridden by `finally` block's return value i.e `4`. Whereas in `fun1()` method return is set to `3` from `catch` block and since the last line of `func1()` never gets executed hence `3` is returned.